# Compile sequence: citing in the glossary

Tags: bibtex, citing, glossaries

I'm trying to add a reference to a source in my bibtex bibliography in one of my glossary entries. However, it remains a questionmark!

When I compile two times in a row, it works fine, though. My compile sequence is the following:

```
pdflatex myFile.tex
makeglossaries myFile
bibtex myFile
pdflatex myFile.tex
pdflatex myFile.tex
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is it only recognising the reference on the second run? What should I add to my make file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the citation is in the glossary, it won't be picked up until the glossary exists. So you first need to run `(pdf)latex`, then run `makeglossaries` to generate the glossary file, then run `(pdf)latex` which will display the glossary so the citation can now be picked up by LaTeX, then run `bibtex` to generate the bibliography file, then run `(pdf)latex` twice to ensure the citations are up-to-date.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{Sample,
  title = "Sample title",
  author = "Sample Author",
  journal = "Sample Journal",
  year = 2013
}
\end{filecontents}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,description={an example with a
citation~\cite{Sample}}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense and worked fine! Thanks!