# Use of glossary for beginner

Tags: glossaries

Problem : Line 11 in MKDoc.tex undefined control sequence when I pdflatex it on TS.
The idx and ind files has zero bytes when I ran Makeindex on TS button

In the main document MkDoc I have several errors

```
line 35  at  \gls{bdc} 
line 37  at  \gls{IEEE}
line 39 at    \Gls{latex}  
line 42 at   \printglossaries
```

I use a preamble for input to MkDoc.tex . The preamble file has use glossaries package.

How to fix this? I don't understand how this works. Here is my MWE. Real example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\include{Preamble_MK2}
% OPTION  2 must make glossaries before each new entry 
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{bdc}
{
name=bdc,description={Borneo Development Coporation}
}

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
name=latex,description={Is a mark up language suitable for scientific documents}
}
\newglossaryentry{IEEE}
{
name=IEEE,description={Institute of Electrical Electronic Engineers }
}
\title{How to create a glossary of terms}
\makeindex              % in order to create the .idx file 
%\begin{document}
\make title
In Sarawak \gls{bdc} plays a key role in the  development\\
\gls{IEEE} plays the professional membership organisation for engineers 
The \Gls{latex} typesetting is suitable for documents that include \gls{maths}\\
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\make` is not a command. I think you mean `\maketitle` but I don't know if that's just a typo in your example or a typo in your code.

Comment: sorry its a typo. Should be \maketitle. TQ.

Comment: `\makeindex` must be before `\begin{document}`. There are not `\newglossaryentry` for "maths" word.

Comment: I had corrected the \makeindex before \begin{document}

Comment: Also I noticed that the .log file does not have package: glossaries term. I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your MWE already exposed in the comments. Another is that there are a `\include{Preamble_MK2}` but not a  file `Preamble_MK2.tex`  in your question (and moreover, it must be `\input`, not `\include`).

Omitting the unrelated code (as it should be in a good MWE), this the minimal **working** example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{bdc}
{name=bdc,
description={Borneo Development Coporation}}
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{name=\LaTeX{},
description={Is a mark up language suitable for scientific documents}}
\newglossaryentry{IEEE}
{name=IEEE,description={Institute of Electrical Electronic Engineers}}
\newglossaryentry{maths}
{name=maths,description={A complex thing}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

In Sarawak \gls{bdc} plays a key role in the  development. 

\gls{IEEE} plays the professional membership organisation for engineers. 

The \Gls{latex} typesetting is suitable for documents that include  \gls{maths}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Note that you must compile `MkDoc.tex`, then  run  `makeglossaries MkDoc` and then  compile again one or two times. See [Compile sequence: citing in the glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111410/compile-sequence-citing-in-the-glossary). In more complex documents you must execute also another auxiliary tools as `makeindex` or `bibtex`. In this case just work with:

```
pdflatex MkDoc.tex 
makeglossaries MkDoc
pdflatex MkDoc.tex
```

This can be make in the system prompt or may be configuring you LaTeX editor (sorry, I do not use TeXshop) or using [arara](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara). You have an example of use of arara in the question linked above.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot.    Just to clarify,  I need to use  the term \input{Preamble_Mk2} ?

Comment: What essential commands do I put in my Preamble files for glossary to work ?

Comment: @mark Exactly, `\include` is mainly for chapters after the preamble. See [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).

Comment: I still don't get the output like yours posted.  How to generate the steps of sequence on TexShop.

Comment: @mark,See the edited answer.

Comment: How to perform the second command " makeglossaries myFile"   I use TeXShop on Mac. The drop downbutton does not have this feature.

Comment: @mark Some editors have a front-end for *some* of these commands, in other editors you can configure the compilation sequence. But anyway, you can always run pdflatex,  makeglossaries, bibtex, etc. when you close your editor in the system prompt. Run also in the system command `texdoc arara`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18853/discussion-between-mark-and-fran).